# Same source code, Eclipse build success but Maven (javac) fails

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-errors

Keep getting this error when compiling using Maven:

```
type parameters of <X>X cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable X with upper bounds int,java.lang.Object
```

Generics type interference cannot be applied to primitive types. But I thought since Java5, boxing/unboxing mechanism works seamlessly between primitive types and wrapper classes.

In any case, the strange thing is Eclipse doesn't report any errors and happily compiles. I'm using JDK1.6.0_12. What could possibly be the problem here?

Answer (score 12):

This issue can occur when your code is generic and it calls another method that has a generic return type. Sometimes the compiler gets confused trying to figure out how to resolve the method call / return type.

It can be resolved by adding an explicit cast to your code.

```
// Old code:
public T getValue() {
    return otherMethod();  // otherMethod has the signature: <RT> RT otherMethod() { ... }
}

// New code:
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T getValue() {
    return (T) otherMethod();   // the cast tells the compiler what to do.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A few things to look at:

1. Both Eclipse and Maven are using the same java/bin installation
2. Eclipse and Maven are using the same libraries, one might have something the other does not.

Comment: I just realized that the compiler shipped with Eclipse isn't the same as Sun's official java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error,use ant.
Because when compile by ant or maven,javac use JDK to compile.But in eclipse,it has JDT,that can compile success.

I add below script in my build.xml file:
`<property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter" />`
Then,ant can build success.

I am not familiar with Maven. Maybe,it can set the compiler?

In my source code,there are many code like this:
`public <X> X find(String hql, Object... values)
    {
        return (X) HibernateUtils.createQuery(getSession(), hql, values).uniqueResult();
    }`

Maybe your code too.

But,use JDT,the success is't the final success,in ant.
build.xml can build success only in eclipse.
when I run ant from windows command,fail. Throw another error:
`Class not found: org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter`

PS, I have copy jar files about JDT in eclipse plugin to ant_home/lib directory.

Wish a little help to you.And our problem can solve.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely has to do something with the JDK versions maven and eclipse are using. Also make sure your Compiler compliance level in eclipse points to the right JDK version.